# new Image() not defined in Dart

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom, dart

I'm playing around with Dart and trying to proxy this [phaser.io](http://phaser.io) js-library.
The startup process of phaser.io requires to generate an image with `var img = new Image();` which turns out in an error message `Breaking on exception: ReferenceError: Image is not defined`.

Usually it's possible to generate an Image element but obviously some of the basic html functionality does not exists.

Do I miss something, do I need to add a special package?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with Dart 1.2 (dev channel).

Please star the issue I filed code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16237

Going back to Dart 1.1 solves the problem.

Comment: The problem is that phaser.io uses `new Image();` in it's js-file, not I. I can't change the behaviour of the third-party library.

Comment: yes, thats right. I want to use a 3rd-party js file which uses `new Image();`. But the error occurs only if I run this in combination with dart.

Comment: That seems to be the same problem I reported a few days ago :-/
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16237

Comment: Do you use DartEditor 1.2 (dev channel)? Try 1.1 (stable)

Comment: that worked pretty well, thank you!! I'll accept your answer, but please update it. thanks